# Android Lint errors on wrong project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I have a multi-module Maven Android project in Eclipse.

The parent module is showing Android Lint errors that belong to the module for the instrumentation tests. The module itself is not showing these errors. The parent module is itself NOT an Android project (does not have the Android Nature)

(Lint is complaining that the api-level of my project is too low:
    Call requires API level 3 (current min is 1):
)

What could be causing the problem? I've never before seen errors of a child module on the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

**The Cause**: I had done some renaming with my project and the modules in Eclipse.

It seems that Android Lint stores the warnings/errors in some persistent database/file. When using the rename refactoring Eclipse didn't know that Lint hat stored some warnings for the project or so it seems.

The renaming changed the project names in such a way that in the end the parent project had gotten the name that previously was that of the app module. Somehow along the way Android Lint must have gotten confused (me too).

**The Solution**: To fix the problem, I manually added the Android Nature to my parent project (by editing .project). Then I used the Android Tools to remove the Lint warnings. Last I removed the Android Nature again.

The warnings didn't come back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, that lint marked 80% of my layouts and string as unused.
Needed 3 hours to fix it..

The problem that lint had was a String with ß in one of my class (I added all my classes step by step and checked with lint every time...)

```
String Eiweiß = new String(e.getString(e.getColumnIndex("Eiweiß")));
```

to

```
String Eiweis = new String(e.getString(e.getColumnIndex("Eiweiß")));
```

Must be a lint bug...infuriating

Hope this helps anyone ;)

Answer (score -1):

Lint is static analyzer tool which shows you warning for some abnormal things present in your code. They might not be right/relevant sometimes.

To avoid that you can right click the project -> fix project -> ignore lint errors

Comment: Thanks :) I knwo what Lint is. However the problem is not the errors, I did fix Lint errors before, but the Parent Project is no Android Project, so why the errors?